# Hotel Key Card Recognition

Tags: probability, statistics

Another problem from  BadCamp Puzzles: http://www-scf.usc.edu/~mearnest/puzzles_by_genre.php

Here is the question: A hotel key card has two ways it can inserted it into the lock. However, it is so poorly labeled that as far you can tell, either way is equally likely to be the correct one. Even worse, the card reader is finicky, so even when you insert it on the correct side, the lock only opens with a known probability, p. Trying the current side takes one seconds, and flipping takes half a second. What strategy minimizes the expected time it will take to open the lock?

Personally, I think I should change the side after inserting side A or B specific times in a row. And I got the probability than side A is correct given $k_1$ times failure of A and $k_2$ times failure of B:
$$P(side\ A\ is\ right | A\ failed\ k_1\ times\ and B\ failed\ k_2\ times)=\frac{(1-p)^{k_1}}{(1-p)^{k_1}+(1-p)^{k_2}}$$

But here flipping will always take half a second. So I got the equations intuitively:
$$\frac{(1-p)^{k_2}}{(1-p)^{k_1}+(1-p)^{k_2}}*\frac{1}{p}+0.5=\frac{(1-p)^{k_1}}{(1-p)^{k_1}+(1-p)^{k_2}}*\frac{1}{p}$$
LHS means expectation time it will take to open if we flip, RHS means that of keeping flipping. If LHS side less than RHS, then we should flip from side A to side B. V.V.

But I am not sure if this is right. Any suggestion or idea will be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: An interesting question! Have you tried working out a concrete strategy if $p=\frac12$? Or if $p$ is very very small? That is where I would start.

Comment: My 2 cents. If p is very very small, the expectation times it take to recognize a correct side is large, and half a second turns to be relatively small that we can ignore it which is exactly what the equation says.

Comment: By a "concrete strategy" I mean a sequence of the form, say, $ABBAABB\ldots$, that says exactly when you should flip.